# Loop until find the match in table

Tags: for-loop, lua, lua-table

I have table and it updated every time if the loop didn't find the Match in table key.

```
for d in io.popen("ls -a /mnt/mediashare/net"):lines() do
    OnlineCheck[#OnlineCheck+1] = d
end
```

First I add the values in to tables then I run another loop to find the match form it if it founds the match the loop breaks but if not then it should reload the table with new values and start matching again. I can't figured it out how to do this all in single loop.

```
for d1,d2 in pairs(OnlineCheck) do

    if d2==NASFolder then
        print("NAS Connected")

        break
    else
        print("NAS is Offline")

    end 
end
```

Comment: Your code begets the question: do we need to close() a pipe explicitly, or that reading all its data is enough?

Answer (score 0):

In Lua 5.2 you should be able to do:

```
local connected = os.execute(('[ -d /mnt/mediashare/net/%q ]'):format(NASFolder))
```

(For Lua 5.1, compare os.execute()'s result with 0.)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to collect lines in table, perform match on the fly:

```
function findUntilMatch(NASFolder)
  for line in io.popen("ls -a /mnt/mediashare/net"):lines() do
    if line == NASFolder then
        print("NAS Connected")
        return
    end
    print("NAS is Offline")
    return findUntilMatch(NASFolder) -- tail call recursion
end
```

Keep in mind - it may run forever ...

**Update**: I have reread the question and now I'm not sure what topic starter means as:

> I can't figured it out how to do this all in single loop.

My original answer was the attempt to write all-in-single-loop including reread info from device.

It is also possible to perform the search by shell (inspired by another answer):

```
local connected = io.popen("ls -a /mnt/mediashare/net | grep '^" .. NASFolder .. "$'"):read()
```

Device reread logic is missed in this example.